# How to extract all the value from a returned Map to a List?

Tags: list, dart, dictionary

So i have this map `final Map<DateTime, List<CleanCalendarEvent>>? events;`. I want to take some item from this Map based on the DateTime, so i do:

```
final recentSunday = DateTime(_selectedDate.year, _selectedDate.month,_selectedDate.day - _selectedDate.weekday % 7);
final nextSunday = DateTime(recentSunday.year, recentSunday.month, recentSunday.day + 7);

selectedCloseEvents = (widget.events?.firstWhereOrNull((date) =>
                date.key.compareTo(recentSunday) > 0 &&
                date.key.compareTo(nextSunday) < 0) ??
            [])
```

this should return all event in a week in `Map<DateTime, List<CleanCalendarEvent>>` format. I need it as  `List<CleanCalendarEvent>`.

I have tried:

```
_selectedCloseEvents = (widget.events?.firstWhereOrNull((date) =>
                date.key.compareTo(recentSunday) > 0 &&
                date.key.compareTo(nextSunday) < 0) ??
            [])
        .value as List<CleanCalendarEvent>?;
```

But it didn't worked. How to select only value from this Map?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/74488636/14891973 answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/values.html) this should give you a list of `CleanCalenderEvent`:

```
_selectedCloseEvents = selectedCloseEvents.values.toList()
```