# How to get certain range of item from dart Map?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dictionary

I have asked similar question before, but there's still something i think about. To begin with, i have an event Map like this:

`final Map<DateTime, List<CleanCalendarEvent>>? events;`

It mapped all my event based on event Date. I want to select some events in certain range of date. I know how to select all the events in one selected date, and put it in a List.

```
_selectedEventsList = widget.events?[DateTime(_selectedDate.year, _selectedDate.month, _selectedDate.day)] ??[];
```

The `_selectedEventsList` is a list of object named CleanCalendarEvent

`List<CleanCalendarEvent>? _selectedEvents;`

Note, my app look like this:
[image]

the lines below the date indicated how many event in one day. I want to get 10 nearest event. How can i do this? If it's a List, i can just get all items in the next 10 indexes, but how to do this in Map?

Comment: your question is too confusing, what your map look like, print it. what you want to select from it. try to make it simple as possible. maybe i am wrong, but from my understanding, you want to select a item in a list, inside a map, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `compareTo()` method to check whether specific `DateTime` is between the specified range.

The example below should help you to solve your problem.

```
void main() {
  final events = <DateTime, List<String>>{
    DateTime(2022, 11, 1): ['party'],
    DateTime(2022, 11, 2): ['party', 'dance'],
    DateTime(2022, 11, 3): ['party', 'gaming'],
    DateTime(2022, 11, 4): ['nothing'],
    DateTime(2022, 11, 5): ['dance'],
  };

  final selectedEvents = <String>[];

  final startDate = DateTime(2022, 11, 2);
  final endDate = DateTime(2022, 11, 4);

  events.forEach((key, value) {
    if (key.compareTo(startDate) >= 0 && key.compareTo(endDate) <= 0) {
      selectedEvents.addAll(value);
    }
  });

  print(selectedEvents);
}
```